# SQLite backup & restore strategy

Tags: java, sqlite, jsp

I am new to this SQLite. So long being used Oracle / SQL which are maintained centrally so DBA manages all these

I am planning to use SQLite DB in one of our Java/JSP application.

The data will be written and read to this DB

I store this SQLite DB file in the same Server as the application itself. There could be a possibility that the DB file getting deleted (for what ever reasons)

I am wondering what backup and restore strategy we could apply here in order to backup the DB incrementally and also restore in worst case.

Simply copying the file (Batch file to copy file from one location to another) every now and then won't work as the DB file may be used

Comment: "Simply copying the file (Batch file to copy file from one location to another) every now and then won't work as the DB file may be used " This does not prevent you from copying the SQLite file.

Comment: @Tichodroma care to elaborate? Thanks

Comment: Just copy the SQLite file. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

How big files are you talking about?

The locking issue could possibly be solved by using LLVM snapshot like described here:
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html

With normal databases, like MariaDB you can do like this:

1. Flush data and lock writes
2. Take LLVM snapshot
3. Release locks
4. Mount snapshot somewhere and make backup with tar, rsync, tarsnap, etc

Then again, to this be usable you probably need to lock the SQLite DB file somehow when creating the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the database is not currently being written to, you can simply copy the file(s).

If there might be concurrent accesses, you must read the database file from within a database transaction.
SQLite has a [backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) for this; the simplest way to use it is to run the [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) command-line shell with the `.backup` command.

There is no mechanism to make incremental backups.